# What's this highlighting in IntelliJ known as?

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

[image]

The Hex value is 29328 but I'm having trouble changing this color in the editor. This is using the Spring framework.

Comment: I believe it's an injected language fragment (in the `General` section). The language being injected is AspectJ.

Comment: Correct, thank you.

Comment: OK, I changed my comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's an injected language fragment (in `Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General`, then `Code > Injected language fragment`).

The language being injected is AspectJ.